# Java Websocket chat on mochahost vps 404 error

Tags: java, android, apache, tomcat, websocket

I just bought a vps online and I've installed apache tomcat 8.0.20 on it. The server is up and running. My websocket app however that was running perfectly on localhost with apache tomcat 8.0.3 keeps giving a

`Status 404: (Not Found)` 
error.

I need help to know if there is any additional configuration I need to do. Or perhaps Mochahost does not support websockets. Or perhaps the Tomcat server needs to run without Apache. Please I need help urgently. I use Autobahn websocket library for android on my client side.My connection url is of the format:

```
ws://domain.com/AppServer/endpointvalue
```

Everything works perfectly on localhost. Though, I wonder if I need to add port numbers to the online server address, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all my fault. I had to include the port number in the websocket url.
Once I included it, it began to work as expected. Thanks: So the path became:

`ws://yourdomain.com:port_number/ServerAppName/endpointvalue`.